# Zone Symbol currentTask Ionic2 error using multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

what does `__zone_symbol__currentTask` mean? Im working on with Ionic2 and caught this object see my attached image. I'm trying to use multiple promises, does these error related to promises?

I also sent an issue to https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/796

[image]

```
useCamera(){

    const getURI = () => {
                const opts: CameraOptions = {
                    quality: 100,
                    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    targetWidth: 200,
                    targetHeight: 200,
                    correctOrientation: true,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };

                let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                    this.camera.getPicture(opts)
                    .then( (uri) => {
                    resolve(uri);
                })
                .catch( (err) => { reject(err) });
            });
            return promise;
        }

        // # 2
        const moveFile = (uri) => {
            const _extension = '.' + this.getFileExtension(uri);
            const _name = this.getFileName(uri) + _extension;
            const _newPath = this.myStoragePath;
            const _newName = 'camera_' + this.hashName() + _extension;
            const _uri = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                this.file.moveFile(_uri, _name, _newPath, _newName)
                .then( (res) => {
                    resolve(res.nativeURL);
                })
                .catch( (err) => {
                    alert('COPY_FILE_CAMERA_ERR ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
            return promise;
        }

        // # 3
        return getURI().then(moveFile)
    }

    //////////////////////
    // THE CALLER OUTSIDE
    //////////////////////
    this.cameraSettings
        .useCamera() // <------------------ entry point
            .then( (res) => {
              alert('USER.TS_OPEN_CAMERA_SUCC ' + JSON.stringify(res))
            })
            .catch( (err) => {
              alert('USER.TS_OPEN_CAMERA_ERR ' + JSON.stringify(err))
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

moveTo, copyFile should call on entryFile and not on this.file
refer to this article
**ionic 1**
https://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/
**ionic 2**
https://github.com/AUSdomgarcia/crud-ionic2/blob/master/src/shared/camera-settings.service.ts

jump to method `useMedia()`